# Spring Data update entity with yesterday's date

Tags: java, mysql, spring, date, jpa

I have some problems with update (and also insert) data into my database. I have an entity with some `integer` properties, some `String` properties, but also is there one property with `LocalDate` type, and it has to be `unique`.

I put a lot of entities like that into the database, but user needs to edit it and update some properties. When I tried to test it and change some `String` property and save updated entity to db I saw this error log in the console:

`Duplicate entry '2019-07-27' for key 'work_day_workday_date_uindex'`

As you can see, Hibernate tries to put object with yesterday's date. But... why? I checked it in traditional ( :D ) way -> by entering `System.out.println` instruction before saving object into database.
Log shows me a correct date in printing:
`WorkDay{id=296, date=2019-07-28, workingTime=8,....`
So I think that the problem is connected with differences in time between database and application.

I found some tips here, in StackOverflow. Somebody said that removing `serverTimezone=UTC` from `application.properties` in SpringBoot could help. And it fixed the problem - yesterday I updated the entity successfully. But today I come back to coding and the problem appeared again.

I hope that maybe some of you had this problem in past and know some solution - it will be very helpful for me :)

Here is WorkDay Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_day")
public class WorkDay implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_workday")
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "workday_date", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private LocalDate date;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "working_time", nullable = false)
    private Integer workingTime;
    @Column(name = "booked_artist")
    private String bookedArtist;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="workday_importance_id")
    private WorkDayImportance workDayImportance;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "workday_employee",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workday_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id_workday")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="employee_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id_employee")})
    private List<Employee> employers;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workDay", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Comment> comments;
```

Here is some code where I perform this operation:

```
    public void setBookedArtist(Long workDayId, String artist){
            workDayRepository
                 .findById(workDayId)
                 .ifPresent(workDay -> workDayDetailsService.saveBookedArtist(workDay, artist));
        }

    void saveBookedArtist(WorkDay workDay, String artist){
            if(artist != null && !artist.equals("")) {
                workDay.setBookedArtist(artist);
                workDayRepository.save(workDay);
            }
        }
```

The entity repository is Spring Data interface which extends JpaRepository.

Best regards!

Comment: Sharing the related code will be helpful, for now, what I can say is probably you are not updating the record but inserting a new record with old data

Comment: Or, quite possibly since it's a `LocalDate`, your time zones are off.

Comment: Okay, I added code where I perform this operation of update. When I disabled `unique = true` for `LocalDate` field it updated correctly, but then I had duplicated date in db. In this app it has to be unique

Comment: Try to add ` workDay.setworkDayId(artist.getworkDayId());` before saving `repo.save()` and let me know the outcome

Comment: @PatelRomil I added that and error the same as before: `Duplicate entry '*yesterday's date*' for key 'work_day_workday_date_uindex'`

Comment: @TravelerVihaan can you share your whole code for more clarification

Comment: @PatelRomil Yes sure, I added code listings into my question. If you need other parts of code, please tell me and I paste them.

Comment: Hello @TravelerVihaan, when you update the data, the expected result is to set date with current LocalDate is it?

Comment: @PatelRomil When I update some data (like `String artist`) i need to left `LocalDate date`. You know, in my application date is field that represent date of every, unique day - I want to make artist or other field mutable, but date should stay the same. I don't touch it when I try to update other fields of entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the Id of workDay before saving the record should work and as we don't want to update the date set `updatable = false` as to below

```
 public void setBookedArtist(Long workDayId, String artist){
            workDayRepository
                 .findById(workDayId)
                 .ifPresent(workDay -> workDayDetailsService.saveBookedArtist(workDay, artist));
        }

    void saveBookedArtist(WorkDay workDay, String artist){
            if(artist != null && !artist.equals("")) {
                workDay.setId(workDay.getId());
                workDay.setBookedArtist(artist);
                workDayRepository.save(workDay);
            }
        }
```

---

```
 @NotNull
    @Column(name = "workday_date", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private LocalDate date;
```

Comment: It works! :) Big thanks to you and other guys who are interested in help me with this problem.